# Manually adding static ip not resolved after a while

Tags: networking, ip, interface, wicd

Hi Unix/Linux community,

I have a small problem with a device I am connecting to my laptop, running Debian Linux. While connected to a router on my `wlan1` interface (using wicd, if that matters), I am adding a static ip to my `eth0` interface using something like `ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev eth0`.

The address and routes are registered correct, but I cannot contact the device until a later point in time. If I try to ping it, I get a number of 'destination host not reachable'. Eventually the device answers and I am able to communicate with it - but not after waiting for this seemingly arbitrary period.

Do you have any ideas what could be causing this? Why can't it just resolve the device immediately?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to your question.

Comment: How long of a time period are we talking about? It may either be the MAC for that IP being saved in the other node's ARP table or it might be NetworkManager (or something along those lines) fixing the routing table after finding the new IP address.

Comment: Usually around a minute. But I have experienced everything from 10 seconds to ~5 minutes. What do you mean by fixing the routing table? I haven't been able to find any changes in it...